# How to tie up MySQL tables properly

Tags: mysql

I have browsed a similar topics at Stackoverflow but haven't found the solution I'm looking for. Please give me an idea how to organise the tables relation. I have 2 tables: the one contains contractor's names and number of contracts for each contractor, the second have invoice's data (like number, amount, date) which relates to each contractor. How should I have to connect these two table correctly? I have an idea to store in the first table contartor's ID,contractor's name and number; in the second - contractor's ID and all invoces' details. But should I store all the invoices' data in one table or create separate table (with invoice's data) for each contractor? I'm newcomer in db-issues and have no enough experience in it. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it correctly. It'd be best to have two tables as the data will be less redundant giving your more efficient space usage.

As an example:

```
CONTRACTOR TABLE
ID        NAME        PHONE
----------------------------------
1         TEST1       619-123-4567
2         TEST2       619-234-5678

INVOICE TABLE
ID        CONTRACTOR_ID        AMOUNT        DATE
----------------------------------------------------------------
1         1                    150.00        2014-04-17 00:00:00
2         1                    150.00        2014-04-18 00:00:00
```

So in the example table, I have two contractors. The first one, named TEST1, has two invoices linked to them in the INVOICE table.

If you're worried about performance, all I would suggest is to add indexes on both tables and foreign keys linking the contractors information with the invoices by the contractors ID.

Answer (score 1):

The two tables should be correct

```
Contractor 
NumberOfContact NameOfContact 

Invoice Data 
Number Amount Date
```

The *Number* of the invoice table would be a FK to contractor *Number* and if that person were to have multiple entries into the invoice table it would be identified by the date.

Answer (score 1):

Your line of thinking is correct. The script would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `contractor` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL,
      `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE .`invoice` (
  `number` INT NOT NULL,
  `amout` INT NOT NULL,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `id_contractor` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`number`),
  INDEX `fk_invoice_1_idx` (`id_contractor` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_invoice_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_contractor`)
    REFERENCES `contractor` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```